# VueJS Extends Methods and Data

Tags: vue.js, vue-resource, vue-component

I would like to extend methods. Example:

```
Vue.extend({
    data: function () {
        return {
            fetcData: 'Test',
        }
    },
    methods: function(){
        return {
            modal: function(){ alert('Modal') },
        }
    }
});
Vue.extend({
    ....
});
```

I use multiple extends.

```
// VueJS Instance
new Vue({
    el: 'html',
    data: {
        effect: true
    },
    methods: {
        xhrGet: function () {
            alert(this.fetcData); // Undefined
            this.modal(); // Undefined
        },
        xhrPost: function (event) {
            alert('xhrPost')
        }
    }
});
```

Error Code:
this.fetchData is undefined. 
this.modal is not a function

Comment: `extend` is use to create component. From your codes I don't see any component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Vue.extend` returns a new Vue component definition that can be later on instantiated using `new` keyword, it doesn't change the global Vue object. So if you want to create a component hierarchy try:

```
var BaseComponent = Vue.extend({
  methods: {
    foo: function() { console.log('foo') }
  }
})

var MyComponent = BaseComponent.extend({
  methods: {
    bar: function() { 
      this.foo()
      console.log('bar')
    }
  }
})

let myComponentInstance = new MyComponent()
```

Check out that [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pkawiak/kg896czu/) for a live example.

Comment: How does this differ from `Vue.component('foo', {extends: bar ...`

Comment: @Jonathan Per vue docs it doesn't, at least in version 2: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#extends